# How to convert SEGY data to numpy (.npy) format

Tags: python, mayavi

I need to convert my 3D seismic data (SEGY format) into numpy (.npy) format. Because most of the libraries only accept the npy format. How can i convert it? thanks

Comment: Did you ask this question of your favourite search engine?

Comment: dude, it's been 3 days I'm searching and checking dozens of pages, couldn't find a solid answer. there were some weird codes for Linux though. But i wouldn't bother to ask here if i could find an answer.

Answer (score 3):

[segyio](https://github.com/equinor/segyio) is your friend.

[This tutorial](https://github.com/equinor/segyio-notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/basic/01_basic_tutorial.ipynb) covers how to load seismic data and export them to numpy.

[This other blog post](https://mycartablog.com/2019/03/12/working-with-3d-seismic-data-in-python-using-segyio-and-numpy-mostly/) specifically covers 3D data.

Answer (score 2):

I have just been exploring segysak for 2D seg-ydata. However, it is geared for 3-D seismic. It stores data in an xarray, which is a step in the right direction. [Segysak](https://segysak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) page. [Basic tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjzTH14va4o)